# Is there a downside to setting a strong default consistency level, but always overriding it with a more relaxed consistency level?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, eventual-consistency

It's only possible to relax, rather than strengthen a Cosmos DB consistency level. **Is there any downside to setting the default as the strongest available (i.e. Strong), and for all statements overriding the consistency level to the weakest (Eventual Consistency)?**

Asking another way, other than the added flexibility, is there any difference in doing this to just having a default of Eventual Consistency?

Answer (score 0):

No downside but if you're always going to relax it I don't see why you would do this. This would only make sense if you needed different consistency levels.

Comment: Thanks. The scenario was a bit contrived in order to be clear, essentially I wanted to know if there was a functional difference between the defaults and overriding consistency levels. Out of interest, why did the Cosmos Team decide to allow relaxation, but not strengthening?

Comment: Technically because of the possibility for race conditions to occur that would result in the client request to strengthen consistency to fail.